# Bootstrap navbar in column - fixed when reaching top of the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with Bootstrap navbar. I want to make it fixed when it reaches the top of the page (with Waypoints), but I have it wrapped in "col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" class.

When I set position: fixed to the navbar, the layout goes crazy - it goes to the right and doesn't fit in the column anymore. I guess it's due to position:fixed taking it out of the flow, but I don't seem to find a good solution to fix it. I tried diving the whole container position: fixed, but it didn't work.

Another question - the Bootstrap navbar itself contains a container and I'm wondering if you can nest a container inside a column. My intuition says no, but what other way can I use to make it act like "col-md-10 col-md-offset-1"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something in your page to become fixed at the top when you reach it when scrolling, you could use Bootstrap's [Affix plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix).

But we could help you more if you could post the code you already have.

Concerning the container class, I don't think that one can be nested in another element, as the container is designed to define the maximum size of your page depending on media queries (1170px, 970px, etc.).

Comment: Thnx for the answer, I'll try it - where can I download it? I don't find any downloadable source, if it's a plugin then I assume it's an additional file?

Answer (score 0):

in the bootstrap class to have special menu in which the menu will be fixed you need to carefully review the documentation on the framework's

Comment: I've been reviewing it for the past 2 days and I have a project deadline today ;) there's something like navbar-fixed class, I tried using it but from what I remember it made my navbar 100% page width. I need all my content, including the navbar, to be wrapped in col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 - or at least for the navbar to have the same width as the rest of the content.

Comment: you do not interfere in it or disable adaptability in your file override styles desired properties